# Where does Synergy store the crypto setting? I want to turn it off

Tags: macos

I installed Synergy on Mac OS Mavericks, to act as a keyboard and mouse server for a win7 desktop.

Initially when I launched it, Synergy for Mac put up a config screen and I selected the "crypto" option.

The other machines aren't set to crypto, and thus would not connect.

I want to disable the crypto setting on the Mac (at least temporarily) until I get this up and running smoothly, but I can't find where this initial choice is kept.

It doesn't seem to be in the server config settings page anywhere that I can see..

I have fully deleted the Synergy app folder, 
Deleted a bunch of Synergy related files via the command line and searching the whole hard drive with find -name *ynergy*  etc,
Then reinstalled from scratch, but the new install found some setting info somewhere and went right to to the server setup and started running with crypto enabled again.

I obviously was not able to fully wipe synergy from the file system since it found that crypto setting and ran it again...

There must be some other file without the word synergy in the filename that's keeping the settings..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, as I expected it to be part of the server configuration.

You can change it by going to MenuBar -> Synergy -> Preferences -> Encryption.